# Как создать переменную в if?

Tags: python, if, variable

Начал изучать питон, нужно создать переменную в if, тобишь что бы она создалась только после "определённых обстоятельств" и что бы её можно было использовать "обстоятельством" для следующего if.
Нашёл что-то только на англоязычном форуме, но не понял.

```
print('Старт')
b = input('какой сейчас год?')
if b == '2021':
    print('правильно')
else:
    g = print('неправильно')    тут я попытался создать переменную
c = input('какой сейчас век?')
if c == '21':
    print('правильно')
elif 'g' in locals():           тут я попытался понять создалась ли она
    print('опять неправильно')
else:
    print('неправильно')
```

Надо сделать так, что бы если в первом вопросе ответ неправильный, то во втором на неправильный ответ написало бы "опять неправильно", а не просто "неправильно", но при этом если ответ на первый вопрос верный, то поле неверного во втором надо написать просто "неправильно", без "опять"

Comment: велосипедите? :) можно пример, хоть псевдокодом, и пояснение, зачем это нужно?

Comment: @Jack_oS агась, хочется что-то простенькое с input и if написать. код сейчас добавлю

Comment: _Нашёл что-то только на англоязычном форуме_, раз нашли, привидите в вопросе код, который нашли, поясните, что не поняли. _слэнг не знаю_, и слава Богу, что не знаете.

Comment: @0xdb не знаю что лучше оттуда коировать, так что вот ссылка - https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5307468f8c1cccb139002c8b

Comment: g = print('неправильно')... print ничего не возвращает, вернее, возвращает None

Comment: @Jack_oS вот у меня None и высвечивается, я думал что это означает отсутствие такой переменной

Comment: вы бы сформулировали, что должна делать программа и как вы это делаете? вас направят в правильное русло

Comment: @Jack_oS я там уже добавил что нужно, но оказалось что пока я код сюда копировал всё заработало, понятия не имею как. Спасибо за помощь.
p.s. А нет, почему-то не добавилось в вопрос

Comment: Старт
какой сейчас год?>? 2021
правильно
какой сейчас век?>? 22
опять неправильно

Comment: @Jack_oS у меня пишет "неправильно", если я неправильно отвечаю на первый вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В питоне обычно это делают так (ибо "явное лучше, чем неявное"):

```
someInfo = None

if условие:
    someInfo = "какая-то информация"

if someInfo:
    print(someInfo)
```

Используемые переменные лучше всё-таки инициализировать в любом случае. Для того, чтобы обозначить тот факт, что в переменной пока нет никакого осмысленного значения и потом этот факт легко можно было проверить через `if`, в питоне используется специальное значение `None`.

Comment: только хотел написать то же самое

Comment: тобишь это по идее создание переменной через if?

Comment: @Empty Нет, если вам именно создать, то это в другом ответе. Как только вы присваиваете что-то переменной - вы её создали. Но это неправильный подход. Проверять потом через `locals` или там через `globals` существует ли переменная - это неправильный программистский подход. Лучше явно создать переменную заранее, просто инициализировать её "пустым" значением.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
if определенные обстоятельства:
    x = 1
```

---

С учетом вашего кода в вопросе: там все сделано верно, только непонятно, что вы хотите получить в `g`.

Comment: это вместо строчки с "созданием" переменной вставить вставить?

Comment: нет, это как оно работает. Вставлять нужно туда, где оно требуется, и в том виде, как оно вписывается в код. Техника "вставить вместо строчки" обычно не работает.

Comment: хочу что бы в "сценарии со вторым else" создалась переменная, указав которую в elif (который в третьем if) мне бы написало то, что я в ней укажу, в данном случае это планировалось как print('опять неправильно')

Comment: Сейчас именно так и происходит. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: теперь заработало, правда я ничего не менял, до этого писало или None вместо "опять неправильно" или с начала "неправильно", а потом сразу же "опять неправильно". Спасибо, а то бы так и мучался xD

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к сказанному ваше решение, если вам не надо хранить значения ответов,  а просто выдать текст ))

```
pre_text = "" if input('какой сейчас год?: ') == '2021' else "опять"
print(f"{'не' if pre_text else ''}правильно")
print(f"{ '' if input('какой сейчас век?': ) == '21' else pre_text + ' не '}правильно ")
```

Можно и в одну строчку, но тогда я сам не прочитаю, что там происходит после того, как написал ))).

Итак, код `pre_text = "" if input('какой сейчас год?: ') == '2021' else "опять"` всегда создает  специфическую переменную `pre_text`,  но по ее значению вам понятно, что дальше с этим делать .